# Can I use an unmanaged switch as a substitute for redundant, stacked switches when using a single network card?

Tags: redundancy, stacking

I am building a network with stacked switches for redundancy. The problem I have is that some of the machines connected to the network will only have one available network card. This card is not a dual port card so I will only have one port.

Do I have pseudo-network fault tolerance with a simple unmanaged switch? The reason I am doing this is because there are many machines on the network and if a managed switch goes down, all the machines should not go with it. If the unmanaged switch goes down it will only take the local machines access with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  What you are proposing is to create a loop in your network with an unmanaged switch and then hoping it understands spanning-tree, or hoping that it forwards spanning-tree through itself so the two upstream managed switches can work out that there is a loop and block one of their downstream ports.

Best case for single-NIC servers is a highly available network switch (dual power supplies, possibly dual supervisors and/or some type of ISSU).  Or you can add a second NIC or create some type of HA cluster with another single-NIC server attached to a different switch.

Comment: I have read a paper from cisco and its description of a redundant star network contradicts what you are saying. Am i misunderstanding it? http://www.cisco.com/web/strategy/docs/manufacturing/industrial_ethernet.pdf  its on page 11

Comment: If you mean figures 4 or 5, the L2 switches they are using are not unmanaged, but full spanning-tree capable switches that will actively participate in STP and use standard loop-avoidance decision-making.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Now a cheeky question..do you have any recommendations? for en indstrial one(2 inputs) and a 8 port one? I'm off to look for them now it was only if you had a recommendation Im gratefull for the answers you already gave. edit I found this one I guess that should be good enough right? http://www.trendnet.com/langen/products/proddetail.asp?prod=405_TE100-S800i