# Do I have to configure a level 2 LACP capable switch for it to work properly on a network with LACP redundant switches

Tags: switch, redundancy, ieee-802.1ax

Ok this question is related to

[Can I use an unmanaged switch as a substitute for redundant, stacked switches when using a single network card?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/13083/can-i-use-an-unmanaged-switch-as-a-substitute-for-a-nft-with-a-single-network-ca)

I have network with two stacked Cisco 2960 switches configured for lacp I have some entities on the network that only have one network card but i want to make use of the redundancy capabilities of the network. If i add a lacp capable level 2 switch at the machine level of these entities can i run two cables back from Them and Then have redundancy? And if i can do i need to configure Them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use LACP to bundle two parallel links into a single logical interface.  You will need to configure the 'level 2' switch so that it knows what interfaces are 'uplink' to the 2960 stack and that it should request/respond to LACP on those interfaces.

You will also need to configure the stacked 2960 switches for a unique port-channel ID for every pair of interfaces connecting to a 'level 2' switch.

Comment: No problem. Depending on your network and in addition to the LACP config, you might want to make sure your trunking configuration limits vlans only to the L2 switches that need them. Especially if you're in a manufacturing environment with 10meg PLC's and similar.

Comment: Thanks @cpt_fink in this case we have vlans for each "Line" so whereever there is one of the layer 2 switches their uplinks will be connected to a port on the 2960 that is open to the specific vlan that the switch corresponds to so the layer 2 switch doesnt see any other traffic than its own vlan. Does this make sense?